# Cannot delete excel file after importing data from it using OleDB, says it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, oledb

I'm importing data from an Excel file in ASP.NET using OleDB. After finishing the import, I want to delete the file using the command System.IO.File.Delete(), but it throws the following exception:

```
The process cannot access the file '...29.xls' because it is being used by another process.
```

I used the following code to open and close the file:

```
Dim fajl As String
fajl = MapPath("fajlovi/" + Request.QueryString("ID"))
        Dim sConnectionStringExcel As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & fajl & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
        Dim objConnExcel As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionStringExcel)
        objConnExcel.Open()
        Dim objCmdSelectExcel As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ZavedenKodPov, Ime, Mjesto, Adresa, JMBG, LicniBroj, ZaposlenKod, Nepoznat, Umro, Penzioner, Reon, VoziloProizvodjac, VoziloModel, VoziloRegistracija, Nekretnina, Datum, KontoBroj, NazivKonta, OpisPromjene, Dug, Pot FROM [Sheet1$]", objConnExcel)
        Dim objAdapterExcel As New OleDbDataAdapter()
        objAdapterExcel.SelectCommand = objCmdSelectExcel
        Dim objDatasetExcel As New DataSet()
        objAdapterExcel.Fill(objDatasetExcel, "XLData")
        Dim tExcel As DataTable
        tExcel = objDatasetExcel.Tables(0)
       '.
       '.
       '.
objConnExcel.Close()
System.IO.File.Delete(fajl)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're closing the connection, but the object isn't being released from memory yet. Like @Jason said, wrap the OleDbConnection in a using statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dispose of the command and connection, preferably wrapped in a using statement. then you should be able to delete the file.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was writing the code for the Using statement when you posted! Here's the MSDN Link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/htd05whh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx